# How can i do overlay subtitle with ffmpeg like in the links provided?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, subtitles, script

I need a script for ffmpeg to do this:

1. Background color (drawbox) for all words like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The idea of having a box with text is to use the [FFmpeg filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) i.e

```
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5"
```

[**drawtext**](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1)

- **fontfile**: The font file to be used for drawing text. The path must be included. This parameter is mandatory if the fontconfig support is disabled.
- **text**: The text string to be drawn. The text must be a sequence of UTF-8 encoded characters. This parameter is mandatory if no file is specified with the parameter textfile.
- **x,y**: The expressions which specify the offsets where text will be drawn within the video frame. They are relative to the top/left border of the output image. The default value of x and y is "0".
- **fontcolor**: The color to be used for drawing fonts. For the syntax of this option, check the (ffmpeg-utils)"Color" section in the ffmpeg-utils manual. The default value of fontcolor is "black".
- **fontsize**: The font size to be used for drawing text. The default value of fontsize is 16.
- **box**: Used to draw a box around text using the background color. The value must be either 1 (enable) or 0 (disable). The default value of box is 0.
- **boxcolor**: The color to be used for drawing box around text. For the syntax of this option, check the (ffmpeg-utils)"Color" section in the ffmpeg-utils manual. The default value of boxcolor is "white".
- **boxborderw**: Set the width of the border to be drawn around the text using bordercolor. The default value of borderw is 0

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I need  to do this subtitle effects with ffmpeg on subtitles.  


Example 1: https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=498980114517638

Example 2: https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=3985582161542560

How can i do it?